# How can I have the date just before the max/last Date and repeat the process on the whole table?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the delta between two values in different dates : the firt is the date Max(COD)

```
 ( Sum({<COD={"$(=Max(COD))"}>*<Contrat={'PRESTA'}>} if([FMonth.autoCalendar.Num]<>[COD.autoCalendar.Num], CapaPresta)) * 130/Hours +(sum( {<COD={"$(=Max(COD))"} >} if(Contrat = 'PRESTA' , Actual)) +     sum( {<COD={"$(=Max(COD))"}>} if(Contrat = 'PRESTA' , Actual_hors_site)))* 130/Hours
```

Now i'm trying to calculate the same value for the date before the max(COD) so I tried this: I replaced the Max(COD) by :

```
 {<COD={"$(=monthend(addmonths(Max(COD), -1)))
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: You could edit your code formatting a little.

Comment: @OrdinaryDraft done!